# Responding to a question about differences of an entity

Tags: logic

Say that someone asks you "What's the difference between those curves (see the image below)?"

[image]

Given the definition of a curve as being *"a line or outline which gradually deviates from being straight for some or all of its length."*

Can you formally answer with "One is orange and the other is blue."? Or because the color isn't a part of the definition of a curve such an answer is invalid?

Comment: I think this question belongs more to Philosophy SE. From the linguistic point of view, you can totally answer "One is orange and the other is blue".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be migrated to Philosophy SE.

Comment: I see that in fact it is posted to Philosophy as well.

Comment: Color is one difference that could be commented on; another is phase; and a third is that one is a cosine and the other is a sine. You could be just as formal as you wanted to be with any of those answers, but  you're not in charge of how what you say is  interpreted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not belong to linguistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriateness of a response derives from the context in which it is asked. If the context is a math class, then appeal to the formal definition of a curve would be appropriate and appeal to color would not be. If you were at a paint store, the opposite would be the case. Answering with a color answer in a math class would be literally true but also overly literal. Nevertheless, it is not *totally* inappropriate in a math class, since precision and explicitness are desiderata in mathematics, and asking "What is the difference..." is really a poor question, since one can refine the question without giving away the answer. One can omit the color difference, which is just a distractor.

One can answer that one is blue and the other is orange, but I don't think one can *formally* answer that way: but the question does not require you to answer formally.

Comment: On the contrary, the question does ask about a formal answer.

Comment: On the contrary, the question asks "What's the difference between those curves (see the image below)?", which say nothing about a *formal* mathematical difference.

Comment: The question you were asked was: 'Can you formally answer with "One is orange and the other is blue."?'